# Such As vs Such that vs Such who

Tags: subordinate-clauses

He is such a boy as doesnot help anybody.
Vs
He is such a boy that doesnot help anybody.
Vs 
He is such a boy who doesnt help anybody.

Which one is correct among the above three? Explain the meaning of correct statement

Comment: None of them sound idiomatic to me. Normally, you would stop the sentence after *he is such a boy* because it would be referring to something previously said. (*Boys like to play. He is such a boy.*) If the sentence continues, you would drop *such* altogether and simply say *he is a boy [something]. . .*

Answer (score 1):

"He is such a boy as does not help anybody" would be normal in some dialects, though I'm not sure it would be normal in the current state of any dialect. The same meaning would be expressed in a way that works in most (if not all) modern dialects by "**he's the sort of boy who does not help anybody**".

In the structure of the "such a boy" sentence, I don't know how to describe it formally, "such a X as Y", where X is a noun and Y is a simple present verb and object, "such a X as" acting as subject, means "the sort of X that Y" (with 'that' replaced by an appropriate pronoun if 'that' is not appropriate). I imagine that linguists have a formal term for it, but I don't know what it is. It can also be a verb in other tenses, though how they interact (including with the tense of the main verb in the sentence) can be complex.

This is differentiated from the standard "such a X" structure, with no 'as', where X is a noun phrase. That is an emphatic way of saying that something is a X. "Such a bad boy", "such a prima donna", "such a lush", and so on. If you say that someone is "such a nerd", you are calling them a nerd emphatically. "Such a nerd as watches TV all day" is observing that the person is a nerd, and saying that they tend to watch TV all day.

"Such a boy" without the 'as' modification would be saying that he is a very typical boy, with whatever characteristics you suppose are typical (or stereotypical) for boys. "He's such a boy, he won't help anybody" is saying that boys don't help people, and he won't help them because he's such a typical boy.

Comment: Therefore "Such a bad boy as doesn't help anybody" sounds ok? Also is it ok to use such variants of "such" in the modern English: "Such a beutefull place!", "it's such (so) fantastic".

Comment: "Such a bad boy as doesn't help anybody" sounds quirky but not wrong. People will tend to read it as the *bad* being bound very closely to the *boy*, the single concept of a 'bad boy', rather than you saying the boy is bad. Think of the "bad boy" images  that have been prevalent in each generation, albeit with different details. "Such a beautiful place" is normal usage. "It's such fantastic" sounds like it belongs in a doge meme - such in that sort of usage needs to be followed by a noun, or noun phrase; "such a fantastic restaurant" would be appropriate.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your intersting answer. A bad boy is sort of Batman? Since the close binding of its parts. figuratively. "You are such a Batman as help everybody".